# How can I force the server side (C#.NET) actions to occur before the client side actions on a button click to avoid a popup to be blocked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, client-side, popup-blocker

I am trying to create three buttons. ButtonAdd adds a new introduction screen and opens an editor in a new window to make changes to said screen. Button1 is only visible if the user has not yet added an introduction screen. ButtonRemove removes the introduction screen. ButtonEdit opens the editor to make changes to the intro screen. ButtonRemove and ButtonEdit are only visible if the user has already added the intro screen. The problem I am having is with ButtonAdd.

ButtonAdd needs to make a server call in order to actually create the object and save it in the database:

```
serverClickFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activity.addIntroScreen();
}
```

ButtonAdd also needs to make a client call in order to open the editor. The URL that opens the editor needs to know certain information about the new object (screenid and contentid):

```
function OpenEditIntro() {
    var tviewer = window.open('../library/edit.aspx?&ScreenID=<%# 
        this.introScreenID %>&contentID=<%# this.introContentID%>')
    tviewer.focus();
}
```

So essentially the server call needs to be made first. OR else the client call doesn't know what to use for screenID or contentID. So I tried to call the client function from the server or code behind. Like so:

```
serverClickFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activity.addIntroScreen();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
           "openEdit", "OpenEditIntro();", true);
    }
```

This worked superbly. Except that popup blockers did not like this. So they wouldn't allow the edit window to popup. Is there any way of getting around this popup being blocked? Or is there anothe approach to this problem that I am just not considering?

Comment: Change `edit.aspx` so that it **doesn't** need the intro screen id. If it is called without a intro screen id then it can create one on the fly. This avoids the 'get the ID, now open a new window' issue that the popup blocker is trying to block.

Comment: Alternatively, add a new endpoint - `bob`. Load `bob` in a new window - it will then effectively call `activity.addIntroScreen();` and redirect to `edit.aspx` once it has the ID.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks! That really helped. Having the new endpoint was essential because I didn't want to make changes to edit.aspx.